# Java_Home no se setea en ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

En la pc tenia instalado el JDK de java 7 y Java 8. En el proyecto utilizo únicamente Java 7. Me ha pasado que por alguna razón (Seguramente una mala configuración) el proyecto me permitió usar una librería de Java 8 y al momento de subirlo al servidor me pinchaba por ese motivo, por lo cual, decidí borrar el JDK de Java 8 de mi maquina para evitar conflictos... No se que fue lo que hice mal pero ahora no me carga mas el proyecto en Grails, no puedo entrar siquiera a la consola interactiva. Me puse a mirar el **echo $JAVA_HOME** y me aparece vació, así que busque toda la ruta de la instalación del Java 7 para poder hacer el correspondiente export:

```
whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 ago 17  2018 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 feb 11 10:32 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Si hago **echo $JAVA_HOME** figura la ruta bien puesta, pero al cerrar la consola y abrirla otra vez, o al reiniciar la pc, me aparece vacía.

Use el comando: **sudo update-alternatives --config java** y le seleccione la opción que creo que es correcta

```
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      modo manual
```

Alguien sabría donde esta el error? no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Mete una línea en el ".profile" para establecer JAVA_HOME

Comment: Hola @EvgeniEnchev, agregue en ~/.bashrc, lo siguiente: export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" estaria correcto??

Comment: EL JAVA_HOME no apunta al ejecutable java sino a la carpet raíz del JRE o JDK, en este caso sería /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre

Comment: @SJuan76 ahi lo modifique y cuando abro mi proyecto de Grails en VS Code me da el error: "The JAVA_HOME environment variable (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre) does not point to a JDK."

Comment: Ahi le puse esta ruta: export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80" y ahi me tomo el Java 7, pero ahora me esta dando un error el proyecto diciendome : Java 8 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK. Cuando el proyecto es para Java 7

Comment: Para resumir, el comando export solo funciona en la terminal donde ha sido ejecutado al abrir una nueva ventana esta no posee la variable, por eso debes escribir los comando en el ~/.bash_profile o en  ~/.bashrc para que al abrir una nueva ventana se encuentren las variables, ademas de esto debes agregar este otro comando export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
esto es porque al registrar el JAVA_HOME también debes registrar los binarios para poder ejecutar por ejemplo el javac.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran ahora sin hacer lo del path me esta funcionando correctamente...debo hacerlo de todas formas?

Comment: Si te reconoce javac y java -version no seria necesario.